# Can the pronoun 'en' replace the verb 'voyager' to express quantity?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, passé-composé

Here is the model answer style the textbook presents me with:

***Modèle: As-tu trop d'argent? (assez)***
*Answer: Non, je n'en ai pas trop. J'en ai assez.*

How would one answer the following question according to the model above:

*As-tu assez voyagé? (trop peu)*

I cannot find any rules regarding this particular circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As-tu assez voyagé [dans ta vie]?**

Oui, j'ai assez voyagé dans ma vie.

Non, je n'ai pas assez voyagé. J'aimerais voyager davantage.

**Please note:**

There is no DE in the sentence after the verb. Now, watch what happens if I change the way I express: "travel enough" in French.

**As-tu fais assez DE voyages** [jusqu'là, dans ta vie]?

It follows your textbook model to a T:

**Oui, j'en ai fait assez.**

**Non, je n'en pas fait assez.**

Generally speaking, the verb FAIRE + assez pas / pas assez DE lets you use the EN to replace adverbial phrases such as **[faire or action verb] assez de, trop de, peu de + plus a verb**. The **en** is for the whole phrase: enough of [doing/making or other action verb] [some thing]/too much [of some thing]/not enough [of some thing], too little/too few [of some  thing].

[I give examples without using too many grammatical terms because I **feel** that's it's easier to absorb the idea and structure that way....]

Answer (score 1):

When you haven't done something enough, you can basically translate it by 'pas assez' and 'trop peu'.

So we can answer your question by :

> Non je n'ai pas assez voyagé.
>
> J'ai trop peu voyagé.

For me, the first sounds better but the second is not bad and you can use it as well as the first ;)